# Function to show a given value in "String" Form

Tags: haskell, show

How do I make a function to do the following?

```
showIt :: a -> String
showIt word = .......?
```

so that if I use

```
showIt "ant"
```

I get:

```
"ant"
```

in Haskell? I know I can use the `show` definition as such for `Int`s

```
*Main> show 3
"3"
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why don't you just use `show`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the "a" to implement Show type class

```
showIt :: (Show a) => a -> String
showIt = show
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert `myself` to `"myself"` you need to put quotes around it. :)

```
Prelude> "myself"
"myself"
```

**Update:**

You can't implement method `showIt :: a -> String` in a useful way because `a` can be anything, including function. You can't show a function, can you?

You can, however, implmement `showIt :: String -> String` like this:

```
showIt word = word
```